# batch file to copy files keeping originals in other folder

Tags: batch, file-transfer

For example I have folder:

```
F1\F11\some files...
F1\F12\some files...
F1\F12\F121\some files..
```

And I have another structure

```
F2\F21\some files...
F2\F22\some files...
F2\F22\folder\some files...
```

names of folders `F11` - `F21`, `F12` and `F22` are equal.

In folders `F21`, `F22` there are fewer files than in `F11`, `F12`.

I need to copy `F2` to `F1` recursively, but files, that will be replaced - should be saved in a backup folder:

```
Fbackup\F11\those files..
Fbackup\F12\those files..
```

This is needed to be able to make "undo" action of that copy. For example I've copied `F2` in `F1` recursively, than I copy Fbackup to `F1` and I have original `F1`.

Comment: Do you need a solution that does this using `.cmd`?  With a Unix shell, I can do it in 5 lines but I'm not sure that's acceptable.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, I need this only in Windows. But, I'm just curious - I'm a linux user actually - how it'll be in bash?

Comment: Looks like someone's already downvoted it (who knows why) but I've given you a couple alternatives below in C shell and `bash`.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a Unix shell, here are a couple alternatives using `bash` or my own C shell.

**C shell solution**

Here's how you might do it with [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm), including the [free version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm):

```
cd F2
foreach i (...\*)
   if ( -f $i ) then
      if ( -e F1\$i ) cp F1\$i Fbackup\$i
      cp $i F1\$i
   end
end
```

The `...` notation is an [indefinite directory wildcard](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/31-Wildcarding.htm) that matches zero or more directory levels, whatever it takes to make the rest of the pattern match.  `...\*` matches every file or directory in the `F2` directory tree.  The [`-e` operator](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/28-FileSystemTests.htm) tests for existence and the `-f` operator tests for files.

This code fragment assumes there are no hidden files or directories of concern.  It also assumes that every directory in `F2` (even if not every file) already exists in `F1` and `Fbackup`.

If hidden files and missing directories need to be considered, the solution would be to set 
[`nonohidden = 1`](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/42-PerThreadVariables.htm) and [`mkdir`](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/mkdir.htm) any missing directories:

```
cd F2
@ nonohidden = 1
foreach i (...\*)
   if ( -f $i ) then
      if ( -e F1\$i ) then
         if ( ! -e Fbackup\$i:h ) mkdir -r Fbackup\$i:h
         cp F1\$i Fbackup\$i
      end
      if ( ! -e F1\$i:h ) mkdir -r F1\$i:h
      cp $i F1\$i
   end
end
```

**`bash` solution**

If you prefer [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) `bash`, you'll need to use `find` in lieu of the `...` wildcard to treewalk the `F2` directory.  Here's what that solution might look like.  (I'm not a `bash` expert so it may be possible to improve this.)

First, create a script, call it `backupscript.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
if [ -f "$@" ]; then
   if [ -e F1/"$@" ]; then
      cp F1/"$@" Fbackup/"$@"
   fi
   head=$(dirname "$@")
   if [ ! -e F1/"$head" ]; then
      mkdir -p F1/"$head"
   fi
   cp "$@" F1/"$@"
end
```

Then run as follows:

```
cd F2
find . -type f  | xargs -I "{}" bash -c "backupscript.sh {}"
```

Comment: Thanks for big response. My bash knowledge is not enough to completely  understand the script, but in general I understood how it's realized.